# MYSQL filter products by attributes

Tags: mysql, attributes, product

How to select products which have all attributes specified by user

For example: user specified attributes to search products: 41,2,4,6

MYSQL structure is:

TABLE: offer

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,

`title_pl` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
```

TABLE: offer_att

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`offer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`att_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

TABLE att

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,

`title_pl` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
```

Comment: CAN YOU GIVE SAMPLE DATA AND OUTPUT?

Comment: define this 'which have all attributes specified by user'

Comment: why did you tag it php?

Comment: on website user can mark checkboxes which are attributes. so that make a list of attributes that user looking. now I have to select products

Comment: And what have you tried? Nothing? Okay, so will I.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT *
FROM offer
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT offer_id
     FROM offer_att oa,
          att a
     WHERE a.title_pl IN (41,
                          2,
                          4,
                          6)
       AND a.id = oa.att_id);
```

P.S. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de3cc/6) is a sample fiddle.

Comment: ok . but if product haven't attribute 6 (have onli 41,2,4) will be listed and should not be

Comment: @jasne you can put the parameters in the POST or GET

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch only offers that have all 4 attributes (41,2,4,6) together then you should use next query

```
SELECT
    o.id
    o.title_pl
FROM
    offer o INNER JOIN offer_att oa ON o.id = oa.offer_id AND oa.att_id IN (41,2,4,6)   
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT oa.att_id) = 4
```

If you want to fetch offers that have at least one of attributes (41 or 2 or 4 or 6) use this one:

```
SELECT
    o.id
    o.title_pl
FROM
    offer o INNER JOIN offer_att oa ON o.id = oa.offer_id AND oa.att_id IN (41,2,4,6)
```

PHP code to generate parameters for your SQL query:

```
<?php
$attributes = array(41, 2, 4, 6);
$count = count($attributes);
$list = implode(',', $attributes);
$query = '
    SELECT
        o.id
        o.title_pl
    FROM
        offer o INNER JOIN offer_att oa ON o.id = oa.offer_id AND oa.att_id IN (' . $list . ')  
';
$db->query($query);
?>
```

Comment: ok . but if product haven't attribute 6 (have onli 41,2,4) will be listed and should not be

Comment: If you use php you can use `count($attributes)` to get **'4'** and `implode(',', $attributes)` to get **'41,2,4,6'** strings.
Then you must take these strings at the right place in query.

Comment: I understand that you are not much good at PHP, so I added PHP code to my answer.